# A property's `fdel` method is not invoked when `__delattr__` is overridden

Tags: python

I have a class like this, in which I have declared a property `x`, and overridden `__delattr__`:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x
    def _get_x(self):
        return self._x
    def _set_x(self, x):
        self._x = x
    def _del_x(self):
        print '_del_x'

    x = property(_get_x, _set_x, _del_x)

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        print '__del_attr__'
```

Now when I run

```
   b = B(1)
   del b.x
```

Only `__del_attr__` get invoked, anybody knows why and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the `__delattr__` of your ancestor to achieve this correctly.

```
class B(object): 
    .....

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        print '__del_attr__'
        super(B, self).__delattr__(name)     # explicit call to ancestor (not automatic in python)
```

And then running :

```
b = B(1)
del b.x
```

Will output:

```
__del_attr__
_del_x
```

Comment: Would you please give me a link to some related document?

Comment: @Satoru.Logic : something like this http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super ?

Answer (score 2):

`_del_x` is called from the default `__del_attr__`.  But since you have overridden `__del_attr__`, the onus is on you to call `_del_x` from inside your `__del_attr__`.